# @Cacheable not working in @Repository class

Tags: spring, ehcache

I have a simple Spring web application. I am using EhCache for caching. I have controller, service and dao. In my sevice I have `@PostConstruct` which invokes a dao method. Dao method doesn't have any parameter and it is annotated with `@Cacheable` annotation.

```
@Cacheable(value="mycache", key="root.method.name")
```

mycache is defined in `ehcache.xml`

In my `@PostConstruct` method, after calling dao method, I extract the cache from cache manager and try to extract the value from cache. Key is dao method name. prb here is I get `null` value.

However if I move same code to my controller. .I get the value ..
is there any difference in behavior of EhCache in `@Repository` class

Comment: There is no guarantee that the `@Cacheable` is already processed and functional, the same applies to `@Transactional`. When using it in the controller I suspect that the latter is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` and all other beans by the `ContextLoaderListener` which means the services and daos are fully operational. Basically don't do something like that in a `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: My code for creating the cachemanager bean is in @configuration class which gets executed before postconstruct is called. And secondly when calling the dao from post construct ..I thought spring beans are already created and ready to use...do you have any documentation supporting link

Comment: Also, my usecase is that I want to load some data at server startup..and assume I don't have spring mvc controller. .I just have jax-ws service..in that case how am I going to load the cache?? Do I need to write servlet listener or create a new class in web project and annotate it with @component and put above code in its postconstruct

Comment: As mentioned don't use a `@PostConstruct` if you are on a newer Spring version create a class that implements `SmartInitializingSingleton` and do the loading in that method. Or create implement the `ApplicationListener` interface and act on `ContectRefreshed` events and then load your data. The point is don't do it in a `@PostConstruct` method as you have no guarantee that AOP is already applied.

Comment: I implemented using both approaches mentioned above. It worked by implementing ApplicationListener interface way. Did not work with SmartInitializingSingleton way

Answer (score 0):

1. You should we add cach name to ehcache.xml

> ```
> <cache name="mycache"
>   maxElementsInMemory="10000"
>   eternal="false"
>   timeToIdleSeconds="7200"
>   timeToLiveSeconds="43200"
>   overflowToDisk="true" />
> ```

2. Implement Serializable interface from entity class:

> User implements Serializable

so that JPA can deserial data when reading data from cache.
It's worked for me.
Hope to help you!